# Use of struct from ".h" file

Tags: c, struct, header-files, extern

Say I have a header file file which contains a struct.

```
Struct aa 
{
    int a;
    int b;
};
```

In `a.c` file I include that header file and I do

```
struct aa first;
```

and then use `first.a` and `first.b` to make changes.

In `b.c` file I include that header file and I do

```
struct aa first;
```

and then use `first.a` and `first.b` to make changes.

Can I do whatever I did in `b.c`? How is linkage done? Does it overwrite the values? How does it work?

Or should I use extern anywhere ?

Comment: "Does it overwrite the values?" --> Did the code attempt to print the values? What was noticed?  Certainly easier to try it than post an SO question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you write `struct aa first;` in a function,

```
// a.c
#include "your_header.h"

void foo(void)
{
    struct aa first;
    first.a = 18;
    first.b = 19;
    ...
}


// b.c
#include "your_header.h"

void bar(void)
{
    struct aa first;
    first.a = 21;
    first.b = 22;
    ...
}
```

then the variable is a local variable of `foo` and `bar` respectively, they
happen to have the same name, but are not the same variable. So the
initialization of `first` in `bar` does not affect in any way the variable
`first` in `foo`.

If you however want a global variable so that the different compile units (meaning
different `.c` files) like `a.c` and
`b.c` can access to, then you need to declare the variable as `extern` in the
header and define it in either `a.c` or `b.c`.

```
// your_header.h
#ifndef YOURHEADER_H
#define YOURHEADER_H

struct aa {
    int a;
    int b;
};

// the "extern" tells the compiler that the
// variable might be defined somewhere else,
// it it's not in the current compile unit,
// it won't give you an error.
extern struct first;

#endif


// a.c
#include "your_header.h"

// a.c defines in this compile unit the global
// variable. This information is important for the linker as well
struct first;

void foo(void)
{
    first.a = 10;
    first.b = 11;
}


//b.c

#include "your_header.h"

void bar(void)
{
    first.a = 100;
    first.b = 200;
}
```

Now when you compile `a.c`: `gcc a.c -c -o a.o`, the compiler knows from the
header file that `first` is a global variable that may be defined in another
compile unit. In this case it is defined in `a.c` itself.

Now when you compile `b.c`: `gcc b.c -c -o b.o`, the compiler knows from the
header file that `first` is a global variable that may be defined in another
compile unit. It is not defined in `b.c`, so the compiler will let the linker
deal with this.

When you link your program: `gcc a.o b.o othermodules.o -o myprogram`, the
linker will know in which object file the variable `first` was defined and will
create the correct offsets for when the program access this variable.

In this case, if you do this in `main`.

```
#include "your_header.h"
#include "other_headers.h"

int main(void)
{
    foo();
    bar();
}
```

then `bar` **will** override the values of `first.a` and `first.b` that were set in `foo`,
because `first` is a global variable.